# jquery full page scroll without plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, timer

https://jsfiddle.net/dewit/xnq0pzx0/1/

```
var currentLocation = 'firstPage';

$(document).scroll(function(e){
    var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop(),
        secondHeight = $('#secondPage').offset().top,
        thirdHeight = $('#thirdPage').offset().top;

    if (scrolled > 1 && currentLocation == 'firstPage') {
        currentLocation = 'secondPage';
        $('body').animate({scrollTop:$('#secondPage').offset().top}, 500);
    } else if (scrolled > secondHeight + 1 && currentLocation == 'secondPage') {
        currentLocation = 'thirdPage';
        $('body').animate({scrollTop:$('#thirdPage').offset().top}, 500);
    } else if (scrolled < thirdHeight - 1 && currentLocation == 'thirdPage') {
        currentLocation = 'secondPage'
        $('body').animate({scrollTop:$('#secondPage').offset().top}, 500);
    } else if (scrolled < secondHeight - 1 && currentLocation == 'secondPage') {
        currentLocation = 'firstPage';
        $('body').animate({scrollTop:$('#firstPage').offset().top}, 500);
    }
})
```

I want to make a full page slider without plugin.

I expect this to detect current page and scroll direction and move next or previous page.

The problem is that while slide is changing, it detects new location and scroll.

As a result, it bounces up and down.

So, I want to freeze this function while slide moving.

But, I don't know how to treat this.

Comment: See the comments below 1cgonza's answer, a cross browser functionality would need a `$('html, body')` selector for animating. Then you could add this line as the first one inside the event listener for a quick fix : `if ($('html').is(':animated')) return;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the event listener is triggered when the user scrolls and also by your animation. From what I see, you want to check all the if/else statements only when user scrolls. Something like the following should help:

```js
var currentLocation = 'firstPage';
// No need to set these inside the event listener since they are always the same.
var firstHeight = $('#firstPage').offset().top,
    secondHeight = $('#secondPage').offset().top,
    thirdHeight = $('#thirdPage').offset().top;

// Helper so we can check if the scroll is triggered by user or by animation.
var autoScrolling = false;

$(document).scroll(function(e){
    var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
    
    // Only check if the user scrolled
    if (!autoScrolling) {
     if (scrolled > 1 && currentLocation == 'firstPage') {
            scrollPage(secondHeight, 'secondPage');
        } else if (scrolled > secondHeight + 1 && currentLocation == 'secondPage') {
            scrollPage(thirdHeight, 'thirdPage');
        } else if (scrolled < thirdHeight - 1 && currentLocation == 'thirdPage') {
            scrollPage(secondHeight, 'secondPage');
        } else if (scrolled < secondHeight - 1 && currentLocation == 'secondPage') {
            scrollPage(firstHeight, 'firstPage');
        }
    }
    
    // Since they all have the same animation, you can avoid repetition
    function scrollPage(nextHeight, page) {
      currentLocation = page;

      // At this point, the page will start scrolling by the animation
      // So we switch this var so the listener does not trigger all the if/else
      autoScrolling = true;
      $('body,html').animate({scrollTop:nextHeight}, 500, function () {
          // Once the animation is over, we can reset the helper.
          // Now it is back to detecting user scroll.
          autoScrolling = false;
      });
    }

 $('h1').html(scrolled);
 $('h1').append("/" + secondHeight);
 $('h1').append("/" + thirdHeight);
})
```

```css
*{
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
html,body{
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
}
.page{
 width: 100%;
 line-height: 100vh;
 text-align: center;
}
header{
 position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
 <h1></h1>
</header>
<article>
 <div class="page" id="firstPage">
  <h2>first page</h2>
 </div>
 <div class="page" id="secondPage">
  <h2>second page</h2>
 </div>
 <div class="page" id="thirdPage">
  <h2>third page</h2>
 </div>
</article>
```

Comment: Yep, nor the original one worked in firefox. See edit above to fix it. Basically the selector for what to scroll in the animation has to be `$('body,html')` instead of just `body` for it to work in firefox.